# Why are errors in a dexie promise resolution not shown?

Tags: promise, dexie

If I do this with a developer console open, I see the error reported in the console:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
}).then(() => {
    throw new Error('Error in vanilla promise');
});
```

If I do this, however, I do not see anything in the console:

```
const query = db.streams.where('id').equals(stream.id);

return db.mycollection.where('id').equals(someId).delete()
    .then(() => {
        throw new Error('Error in dexie callback');
    });
```

I can add the following, and then I see the first error reported twice (once by whatever was already reporting it and once from this listener), and the second error reported once (from this listener):

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', ev => {
    console.error('unhandledrejection', ev.reason);
});
```

Why are these two different?  Is there some way for me to get consistent error handling, regardless of whether the initial promise is coming from dexie or not?

I'm using dexie 2.0.4

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 77.0.3865.120

Comment: The "unhandledrejection" event does not seem to be called when I try.